# How to trigger 12v environment on PowerBank

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, power, battery-charging

**The Desired Result**: via rechargeable battery, power a 12v 1 meter led strip that takes 1.2 amps.

I have purchased an orico power bank with 12v 1.35amps output as it meets the dimensions needed for the project.
[https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0SC-00TX-00002&cm_re=12v_power_bank-*-0SC-00TX-00002-*-Product](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0SC-00TX-00002&cm_re=12v_power_bank-_-0SC-00TX-00002-_-Product)

**The issue:** the power bank automatically detects the charing environment and currently is stuck with the 5V output option and can not power the leds.

**Possible Solution:** I am curious if there is a way to, perhaps use a micro-controller to cause the power bank to detect the desired charging environment to output the 12V.

**alternatively:** if there is another power bank that outputs 12V and 1.35+amps close to these dimensions: 102 x 76.8 x 21.5 mm that doesnt require additional steps, id be open to purchasing another. ( I have searched quite a bit for rechargeable packs and seem to have only found the one listed above)

or

some configuration of rechargeable batteries like the 18560 to power it (I'm just hoping to use a recharge pack as it often has additional feature to keep it more safe)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Without a schematic of how you've wired everything up we are working in the dark and can't help you. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Consult the manual, or ask the manufacturer or vendor how, or if, it can be set to provide 12 volts.

Comment: Other useful links include: [USB Charger Fooled into Variable Voltage Source {Hackaday}](https://hackaday.com/2017/06/02/usb-charger-persuaded-to-variable-voltage-source/), [Unlocking 12V Quick Charge on a USB Power Bank{Hackaday}](https://hackaday.com/2017/03/04/unlocking-12v-quick-charge-on-a-usb-power-bank/) and [How To Bitbang Quick Charge 2.0 - Without ICs {YouTube}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYRZ0t5eyjE)